# PHP Can't Execute Shell Script That Kills Process

Tags: php, bash, shell, sh

I have a script called `turn_on.sh`.
I also have a script `turn_off.sh`.

```
turn_on.sh
```

Starts a process

```
turn_off.sh
```

Simply kills the process (via kill -9 pid)

Running on the command line, everything works fine.

Calling these scripts from php simply doesn't work. I've tried `shell_exec`, `exec`, `system`. Nothing seems to work. There is no errors anywhere.

I've tried `chmod 777` both shell scripts. Still doesn't work.

Example code:

```
   $val3 = exec($to_run,$val2,$val);
```

$val2 and $val having nothing in them.

PHP `safe_mode` is off

Comment: do you have an error that gets returned from the php interpreter? Furthermore running under the php cli process, the process itself might have insufficient permissions to deal with starting or killing other processes.

Comment: No errors returns from the responses of shell_exec, exec, system.

Comment: can you post the php code

Comment: how would i be able to check if it has sufficient permissions?

Comment: some code would be very helpful.. plus to kill processes you would likely have to be in an elevated state. Can you kill the same processes without going sudo?

Comment: Is the php script starting and stopping the process or is it just stopping it? Because it could be the process was started by a different user, and  you just can't go killing other users' processes (unless you're root of course, which you aren't). Also inside the scripts in the first line after #/bin/bash try putting set -x, so you'll get a complete debug.

Comment: I agree with Cristian Cavalli. kill -9 will require that the scripts are executed by the same user as the php script. Possible to post code and results of ls -al on the scripts?

Comment: Scripts have -rwxrwxrwx permissions. The PHP process is supposed to both starts and stops. Right now it isn't doing either :-\.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to several reasons:

1) You run your PHP script via apache, so the www-data user didn't have permission to run the two shells scripts.

2) You run your PHP script via apache, so the www-data user didn't have permission to start or kill the process.

3) ...

Try to redirect the standard and error outputs of your scripts in a log file for better analysis. You could also use `set -x` to get a more complete debug trace.

Comment: I am on ngnix. But yes I do see www-data user is the one that needs permission (makes sense), but shouldn't chmoding the files get around the need for this?

Comment: @K2xL You must give the permission for running the script to the ngnix user (www-data maybe). And you must give the permission to starting and killing the process in the script. You could add an entry in the sudoers file for the ngnix user to be able to start and kill the process...

Comment: is there any way to do this without having to modify the sudoers file? how do i give permission to the script to a specific user?

Comment: @K2xL Have you try to see the output of your shell scripts when they are running by your PHP page (with a redirection of outputs 1 and 2) ? It would be nice to do it at first, to see exactly where the problem is located (if it's a problem of permission or not, ...)